# ¿Por qué me lanza el mensaje " 'javac" no se reconoce'." cuando compiló?

Tags: java, visual-studio

quiero usar java en visual studio code, ya instale la extension de los packetes y el archivo jdk, pero cuando quiero ejecutar un proyecto me sale  el siguente mensaje: "javac" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: Buenas, Álvaro, pues parece que no se ha instalado correctamente el JDK o no se ha incluido en tu variable de entorno PATH. Revisa el valor que tiene esa variable y añade la ruta donde has instalado el JDK.

Comment: Probaste reiniciar?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.